# Is it possible to run Ionic application as a service?

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic-framework, service

I am building an ionic2 application.
It is based on transmitting GPS data.
I want to transmit the GPS data to the remote server (so other clients can see the actual position) of target device.

And I'm stuck here at two moments.

1) I want to transmit the GPS data only when it is required. So, when any client wants to see where is the target device and watch the position in real-time.

2) I want to transmit the GPS data, even if the application is closed. (I think it should be run as a service, like the Whatsapp, or Facebook messenger are working. Whatsapp transmitts GPS data even if it is closed, but the Facebook messenger shows income messages when you receive new messages without push notification..)

What are the posibilities? What is limited in these possibilities? Why?

Comment: You can try this plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-geolocation/

Comment: One more plugin for background mode https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode/

Comment: Background it is when you open another program and the application goes in background mode. But I'm asking about of totally closing the app... It should work as a service. It should send GPS coordinates to a server when asked